# Need to hide a column in a table on button click

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a button that calls a macro which opens up a table.  I'd like to hide a column in that table when it opens.  The macro opens the table tChart1_Reportable and I'd like to hide the ID column.

I figure this has to be done in VBA with the RunCode action selected in the macro.

I haven't had luck finding code that works.  Found this online but it doesnt work in the current form:

```
   Public Sub SetColumnHidden() 

 Dim dbs As DAO.Database 
 Dim fld As DAO.Field 
 Dim prp As DAO.Property 
 Const conErrPropertyNotFound = 3270 

 ' Turn off error trapping. 
 On Error Resume Next 

 Set dbs = CurrentDb 

 ' Set field property. 
 Set fld = dbs.TableDefs!tChart1_Reportable.Fields!ID 
 fld.Properties("ColumnHidden") = True 

 ' Error may have occurred when value was set. 
 If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
 If Err.Number <> conErrPropertyNotFound Then 
 On Error GoTo 0 
 MsgBox "Couldn't set property 'ColumnHidden' " &; _ 
 "on field '" &; fld.Name &; "'", vbCritical 
 Else 
 On Error GoTo 0 
 Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("ColumnHidden", dbLong, True) 
 fld.Properties.Append prp 
 End If 
 End If 

 Set prp = Nothing 
 Set fld = Nothing 
 Set dbs = Nothing 

End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to open a query instead of the raw table? Then you have complete control over which columns are displayed, which records are displayed (if you want to filter) and what order the records are displayed in.

Comment: What exactly about it does not work, some sort of error? Also, what is the column name and table name that you're trying to hide?

Comment: There is no error message, but the table still shows the column.  Table: tChart1_Reportable, Column: ID

Comment: And the table opens so it can be edited by front-end users, but I still need to preserve the ID column for archival purposes and linking to other tables.  Kind of complicated, and this is the best way I could think to do it.

Comment: In that case, what @Skippy mentioned would likely be your best option. Just write a query for the Front-End user that omits the ID column.

Comment: If I had to guess, (with the way the code is written), it is most likely working properly, its just not updating to the GUI. In other words, if you reopened the Table it would be hidden. The code would require some sort of Requery option, although I am not 100% certain that is possible with a table in that format.

Answer (score 0):

Although you really should think about using a query to accomplish this goal instead, the problem with this code is definitely that the Table itself does not refresh the hidden property on execution.

That being said, this would likely suffice as a solution to this problem:

```
Public Sub SetColumnHidden() 

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database 
    Dim fld As DAO.Field 
    Dim prp As DAO.Property 

    Set dbs = CurrentDb 

    'Set field property. 
    Set fld = dbs.TableDefs!tChart1_Reportable.Fields!ID 
    fld.Properties("ColumnHidden") = True 

    DoCmd.Close acTable, "tChart1_Reportable"
    DoCmd.OpenTable "tChart1_Reportable"

    Set prp = Nothing 
    Set fld = Nothing 
    Set dbs = Nothing 

End Sub
```

To work this through a query, create a new query with `Query Design`, open it in SQL view. Your query should like something like this:

```
SELECT [Field1],
[Field2],
[Field3]
FROM tChart1_Reportable
```

Basically, add every field you want to view (by the field's name), removing the "ID" field from the list. This will accomplish what you're attempting to do. As far as why the code is not working for you, all I can say is it should be.

Comment: Hm, that opens the table but the ID column is not hidden.

Comment: You are probably hitting an error somewhere in the code. But the "error handling" is bypassing it. Try the updated code instead.

Comment: The updated code worked without error and opened the table, but the ID column is still visible.

Comment: Something seems off, although its difficult to figure out without more information. How are you running the code, this is through a macro?

Comment: Right now I've just been running it from the module in the Visual Basic Editor.

Comment: Add this line at the bottom after `Set dbs = Nothing`: `MsgBox "Code ran successfully"`

Comment: Ran the code- table opened with ID visible, and the msg box popped up.

Comment: Well, for whatever reason it looks like the code is not working for you. Could be the version of Access you have or a problem with the database somehow? But, I added a little bit of additional information to the answer, it should show you how to accomplish the same basic proceedure through a query instead of hiding the column on the table itself. Then you would just open the query, instead of the table, this is generally a safer way for Front-End users to interact with your database anyway.

Comment: This started working, I was playing around with manually hiding and unhiding the column and then when I tried to run the code again it worked (???).  Thanks for all of your help!